# NGINX redirect from old to new domain

Tags: redirect, nginx, http-status-code-301

I need to redirect requests like `http://domain.com/?part=word` to `http://another_domain/?part=word`, 'word' may be different

My nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  domain.com www.domain.com;
  rewrite ^/?part=(.*)$ http://another_domain/?part=$1 permanent;
}
```

redirect does not work, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

instead of specifying what words you want to handle, you can just tell nginx to append all the args

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name old.example.com;
  return 301 http://new.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Update:
I've recently found out that `$request_uri` already contains the query string, and thus the extra part that I've had (`$is_args$query_string`) would not be necessary. I've updated the above part and removed the extra query  string.

Comment: See Nginx documentation for this use case: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html